# Is there a way to retrieve the client IP address using a Python backend server

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, fastapi, starlette, uvicorn

the setup in question looks like this:

my web app implemented using `fastapi` and deployed using `gunicorn` and the `uvicorn` worker class, is behind an `nginx` proxy on the same host with IP address `172.31.x.x` (and behind other remote appliances like VPN concentrator, etc.)

`nginx` is configured like:

```
location / {
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    set_real_ip_from 172.31.x.x/32;  # well-known vpn concentrator

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.x.x:5045;
```

`gunicorn` is configured like:

```
OPTIONS="--bind 127.0.0.1:5045 --bind 172.31.x.x:5045 --forwarded-allow-ips=127.0.0.1,172.31.x.x --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.Uv
icornWorker --log-config config/logging.conf"
```

in `fastapi` using the `starlette.requests.Request` object (named `request`), `request.client.host` prints the interface IP address of the server that hosts the web app (that is `172.31.x.x`)

`request.headers["x-real-ip"], request.headers["x-forwarded-for"]`both print the IP address of the appliance before my proxy, which is a well-known firewall appliance in my company.

What I would like to ask is:

1. is it possible to print the whole `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header to see the intermediary proxying services ?
2. how to retrieve the real client IP address of my end user (essentially overriding the well-known whitelisting IP address) ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for it?